# Can the Default blog page layout be edited?

Tags: 2007, page-layout, blog

I have created custom page layout for my other 'normal' pages.

However i can't find how to set my blog to use my page layout? Or any other page layout for that matter.

Is it possible to change a the page layout that a blog uses?

Comment: Hey Jamie,

This is quite a complex process if you have limited development experience in SharePoint, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: bummer, i certainly am a sharepoint newbie as it is. I'm a front end dev. So if its really that complex i will pass the message on to my client and let them know its rather difficult. Obviously as you say its slightly more difficult than changing the pages layout?

Comment: It's only because it is a built in template, the actual blog tempalte in the hive is just an install script. You would need to create a template and export it, then import this into visual studio. The alternative cleaner way is to make a custom module that has the page layout and adds the required features, lists, libraries and webparts.

Answer (score 0):

Since page layout functionality belong to the publishing infrastructure,
you can try activating the Publishing Infrastructure feature, this will give you the ability to change the page layout on your blog site and after changing it, deactivate the Publishing feature.
I think this will do the trick, but keep in mine that Microsoft doesn't support this scenario.